# Firebase 3.x - Token / Session Expiration

Tags: session, firebase, token, firebase-authentication

Does anyone know how long would it take for the token to expire? There no option now to set the token validity on the console.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Since May 2016 Firebase Authentication login sessions don't expire anymore. Instead they use a combination of long-lived account tokens and short-lived, auto-refreshed access/ID tokens to get the best of both worlds.

If you want to end a user's session, you can call [`signOut()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#exceptions_5).

Comment: Frank, could you elaborate on the details? For instance, FB long-lived token expires in 60 days but auto-refreshed once a day when someone makes any request but will force login flow if no request is made.

Comment: The latest release of Firebase Authentication gives mes this "[FirebaseDatabase] Authentication failed: expired_token (Auth token is expired)"

Comment: In the new Firebase, session only expires if you have a big changes in your account, let's say you change your password, etc.

Comment: My token expire every one hour, i have added SHA-1 in firebase console, I send the token to my custom server for verification. Could anyone help me why my expiry time is just one hour.

Comment: It seems this has changed yet again, and now the tokens do expire after a while.

Comment: This hasn't changed. Login sessions don't expire. But the short-lived tokens (I think they're called ID tokens) are valid for only an hour. When you use a Firebase SDK, it auto-refreshes those short-lived tokens.

Comment: Since the ID tokens expire once an hour, how can we use them to authenticate with a custom server? I followed the directions on how to [verify id tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) on my server, but now the server can't recognize a logged in user after only an hour passes.

Comment: options 1: have a response intercept and refresh the token if the token is invalid and remake the API call.

Answer (score 32):

Its does expire. After one hour logged in the token id expire. If you try to verify sdk returns a error "Error: Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh token from your client app and try again. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token."

Is There such a way to change expiration time to Firebase token, not custom token.

Anybody that know how this really works.

Comment: Any solutions running into this issue?

Comment: you could always use `currentUser.getIdToken()` but my problem is that this returns a promise :-/ I don't want to do async stuff in my request interceptors...

Comment: @ProblemsOfSumit you can pass a boolean 'false' as a parameter to getIdToken to make it synchronous.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone that is still confused, it is all [explained in great detail here](https://medium.com/@jwngr/demystifying-firebase-auth-tokens-e0c533ed330c)

> If your app includes a custom backend server, ID tokens can and should
> be used to communicate securely with it. Instead of sending requests
> with a user’s raw uid which can be easily spoofed by a malicious
> client, send the user's ID token which can be verified via a Firebase
> Admin SDK (or even a third-party JWT library if Firebase does not have
> an Admin SDK in your language of choice). To facilitate this, the
> modern client SDKs provide convenient methods for retrieving ID tokens
> for the currently logged-in user. The Admin SDK ensures the ID token
> is valid and returns the decoded token, which includes the uid of the
> user it belongs to as well as any custom claims added to it.

Comment: the token still expires after one hour and this does not solve the issue

Answer (score 6):

If the above answer is still confusing to you,
This is what i did:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
    if (user) {
        const lastSignInTime = new Date(user.metadata.lastSignInTime);
        const lastSignInTimeTimeStamp = Math.round(lastSignInTime.getTime() / 1000);
        const yesterdayTimeStamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) - (24 * 3600);
        if(lastSignInTimeTimeStamp < yesterdayTimeStamp){
          await firebase.auth().signOut()
          this.setState({
            loggedIn: false
          });
          return false;
        }
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: true,
          user
        });
      }
    })
```