# How to implement timeouts for firebase email authenticated logins?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When I login to to my firebase webapp using email and password then I still remain logged in even when I open the application the next day.

It seems to me that when we login to the firebase webapp using email and password based authentication the user will remain logged in until and unless he explicitly logouts.

Is it possible to timeout the login sessions so that if someone comes to use the same workstation after some time and the previous user has not logged out then the new user needs to reenter the credentials?

Comment: Firebase Authentication sessions do not have a time-based expiration. If you want that functionality, you will have to build it yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487283/firebase-3-x-token-session-expiration