# Firebase - Losing Auth Session After An Hour

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I added Firebase auth to my Reactjs (and Redux) web app and everything works perfectly.  I'm using email / password sign in, and call firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword which persists on reloads, tab changes, etc.  However, after about an hour, the auth session appears to expire and currentUser is set to null.  It feels like there should be a setting somewhere in the Firebase console, but after searching through it, I can't find anything.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Is it the user session that is expiring or is it the token? ID tokens expire after one hour (which can't be changed), but are automatically refreshed behind the scene. User sessions don't expire after an hour. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487283/firebase-3-x-token-session-expiration.

Comment: I think that for whatever reason, the token isn't being refreshed automatically.  That link suggests calling firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken to manually refresh, but I can't do that since currentUser is null after an hour.  I guess I could set a 55 minute timer and refresh it that way, but it seems really hackish...  Any ideas on why it isn't refreshing?

Comment: User should not be logged out on ID token expiration. There is something else going on here. User is logged out if there is a big account change (user deleted, password changed, email changed, password reset, etc). Are you using `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` listener to determine the initial state of a user?

Comment: I set `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` up last night with a console log, but it's not helping too much.  Immediately after logging in, it logs what appears to be a normal logged in status containing an email, refreshToken, uid, etc.  Refreshing the page logs the same thing, however after an hour goes by, the log just returns 'null'.  After that time, refreshing still returns null and the only way to get the user data back is to log out and back in.

Comment: Firebase tokens are by default set to live max 1hours.

Comment: Perhaps you need to save the UID of the user before attempting a token refresh. LocalStorage?

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue, `onAuthStateChanged` was always triggered after 1 hour and the user was disconnected. And `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)` didn't help either, all because... Token Service API had to be enabled for my Google API key in the Google console. Problem solved!

Go to Google Cloud platform, type "Token Service API" in the search bar, click on it in the results, and click "Manage" on the new page, and finally "Enable API".

Comment: This was the solution for me! Thank you so much!

Comment: Could u please explain what exactly i should do. Where i should enable Chris Token Service API?

Comment: @Leo I added details. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for this information. It was enabled for me , but sometimes after some days my user is log out for some reason. Need to check this deeply =)